# How do I define a ListView with contents in the layout XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm prototyping an Android application, and am trying to define the UI before writing any Java code.  The basic XML layout stuff works fine, but I can't figure out how to add a `ListView` with contents.   Adding the `ListView` inside a `LinearLayout` works fine, but I can't add anything (not even another `LinearLayout`) as the *contents* of this `ListView`.

I tried the fairly obvious way of doing this:

```
<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="2">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:text="Line One"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView android:text="Line Two"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView android:text="Line Three"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ListView>
```

But it failed (at runtime) with an exception when trying to start the activity:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView.
```

The SDK documentation for the XML layout language is fairly poor, and I can't seem to find any obvious way to make this work.  What am I missing?

Bonus question:  is there a way to detect problems in the XML layout at *build-time*, instead of waiting for Android to throw an exception at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The basic XML layout stuff works fine, but I can't figure out how to add a ListView with contents.

You can't. Your best options are to either use the `ListView` element with the attribute `android:entries` pointing to a an array resource(this will show a simple `ListView` of `Strings`) or simulate the `ListView` by replacing it with a `ScrollView` and then add the content you want in the `ListView` as the content of the `ListView`(but it should be something that simulates the rows and not separate content).

> Bonus question: is there a way to detect problems in the XML layout at
>   build-time, instead of waiting for Android to throw an exception at
>   runtime?

I guess android already does that. Placing content in a `ListView` is ok in the xml layout(probably) because the `ListView` is a `ViewGroup`, but later when android actually tries to add the content to the `ListView` it will fail, as the exception says, because the operation is unsupported.

Comment: Okay, got it.  Thanks for the quick and thorough answer!

Answer (score 1):

you don't really add other views "into" the list view because it's not a type of layout where you can add nested layouts and views.

refer to this tutorial as it shows how to properly populate and manipulate your listview

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html